# jQuery, launch one bunch of async calls after another

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I have two functions that run async call in cycle, and I need all first calls to be completed before second fires. How to it it with jQuery?

Here is my example:

```
function getRandomInterval(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

// All async calls go here
function asyncCalls1() {

    // multiple async calls here, 5 is only for example (there is do while inside, I don't know final condition/counter)
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var tmp = getRandomInterval(1000);

        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('asyncCalls1 fired ' + tmp);
        }, tmp);
    }
}

// Next part of async calls, first bunch should be already completed
function asyncCalls2() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var tmp = getRandomInterval(1000);

        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('asyncCalls2 fired ' + tmp);
        }, tmp);
    }

}


jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    asyncCalls1();
    asyncCalls2();

    // need something like
    //asyncCalls1().then(asyncCalls2);
    
    // All asyncCalls1 should be complete first, and next fires asyncCalls2 function

});
```

I can return dfd.resolve from one of the async calls, but how to control the whole bunch of them (I don't know how much calls could be, so cannot use counters)?

I use it in SharePoint workflows - I need to stop all of them before start them again..

Best regards, Gennady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize Promises and use syntax you suggested - `asyncCalls1().then( asyncCalls2 )`

```js
function getRandomInterval(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

// All async calls go here
function asyncCalls1() {

    let a = 1; 
    // multiple async calls here, 5 is only for example (there is do while inside, I don't know final condition/counter)
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var tmp = getRandomInterval(1000);

            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('asyncCalls1 fired ' + tmp);
                if(a++ === 5) resolve(); // condition inside that while
            }, tmp);
        }
    });
}

// Next part of async calls, first bunch should be already completed
function asyncCalls2() {

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var tmp = getRandomInterval(1000);

            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('asyncCalls2 fired ' + tmp);
            }, tmp);
        }

}


asyncCalls1().then( asyncCalls2 );
```

What i did is, I made asyncCalls1 return a Promise, which is resolved when last call is successfully returned (I guess you have to use the condition in your while loop). Then you can call the second asynCalls.

Since there is no need for jQuery in this exapmle, I removed it.

If you didn't want to use then, and make syntax simpler, you could use async/await.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```js
function asyncCall(name,cb) {
  // define the mkTO ("makeTimeOut") function within the 
  // scope of asyncCall(), so it shares name, n and cb 
  // with its parent scope:
  const mkTO=(t)=>
    setTimeout(()=>{      // timeout action follows here: 
      console.log(name+' fired after '+t);
      if (cb&&!--n) cb(); // call cb() after last action has fired!
    } ,t );
      
  var n=5;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var tmp = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(1000));
    console.log('started '+name+' with '+tmp+'ms.')
    mkTO(tmp)
  }
}

asyncCall('first',()=>asyncCall('second'));
```

I simplified your functions a little bit (I chose the same function with different parameters for the second call - feel free to do something else there), but the structure should still be clear:

- the `asyncCall()` starts a series of `setTimeout()` calls.
- In the "action part" of the setTimeout I carry out a countdown from the total number of calls (`n`) and when this countdown reaches `0` and a further callback (`cb`) is defined, then
- this callback function is invoked: `cb()`

Comment: Thank You much for great answer, @cars10m! If You don't mind - Ill mark Kudlas's post as answer, but Your approach is elegant! Best regards, Gennady

Comment: :D no problem at all! His approach uses your original syntax and is also very interesting, as it uses the more modern "Promise" paradigm. I read it with great interest too!